# c# wpf TreeView issue with selecting root item

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have an strange issue with a WPF TreeView in C#. When running my App i want to expand and collapse all nodes from the selected TreeView node. When i select a root node, the IsSelected property is not updated. When i manually expand the root node and click on the child node, the IsSelected property is updated. The problem is that when i use the context menu to expand and collapse the child nodes on the root node, the root node is not expanded. When i expand the root node after using the context menu i can see that all child nodes have been expanded correctly.

I have searched a lot in the internet, but couldn't find a similar issue. Furthermore i read a lot of tutorials and howtos on C# WPF TreeViews. So far my implementation seems to me to be correct, thats why i don't understand why the root property IsSelected is not set when clicking on the node.

Can anyone help me? I have implemented the TreeView, ViewModel and Model as follows. Thanks in advance

BR

Michael

---

```
<TreeView
Grid.Row="1"
Grid.Column="0"
Margin="5"
ContextMenuOpening="FrameworkElement_OnContextMenuOpening"
ItemsSource="{Binding HierarchialTestObjects}"
SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged">
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:HierarchialTestObjectViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </Style>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
<TreeView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding ExpandAllTreeItemsCommand}" Header="Expand All" />
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding CollapseAllTreeItemsCommand}" Header="Collapse All" />
    </ContextMenu>
</TreeView.ContextMenu>
```

```
namespace mynamespace.subspace.report.data
{
// ... usings removed

public class HierarchialTestObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<HierarchialTestObject> Childs { get; set; } = new List<HierarchialTestObject>();

    public List<string> Path { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    public List<string> ParentPath => Path?.AsEnumerable()?.Reverse()?.Skip(1)?.Reverse()?.ToList();

    public IHierarchialItem Item { get; set; }

    public HierarchialTestObject(IHierarchialItem item)
    {
        Item = item;
        Name = item.ShortDescription;
    }

    public void SetChilds(IEnumerable<IHierarchialItem> childs)
    {
        childs.ToList().ForEach(c => Childs?.Add(new HierarchialTestObject(c)));
    }
}
}
```

ViewModel

```
namespace mynamespace.subspace.report.viewmodel
{
// ... usings removed

public class HierarchialTestObjectViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public delegate void NotifyTreeItemSelected(HierarchialTestObjectViewModel item);

    public event NotifyTreeItemSelected OnTreeItemSelected;

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected != value)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _isSelected, value, nameof(IsSelected));
                if (value)
                {
                    // this is a hack-ish workaround because i cannot use PRISM or other similar libs
                    OnTreeItemSelected?.Invoke(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (_isExpanded != value)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _isExpanded, value, nameof(IsExpanded));
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IconType));
            }
        }
    }



    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _name, value, nameof(Name));
            }
        }
    }



    private IHierarchialItem _item;
    public IHierarchialItem Item
    {
        get { return _item; }
        set
        {
            if (_item != value)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _item, value, nameof(Item));
            }
        }
    }


    private List<string> _path;
    public List<string> Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set
        {
            if (_path != value)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _path, value, nameof(Path));
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<HierarchialTestObjectViewModel> _childs;
    public ObservableCollection<HierarchialTestObjectViewModel> Childs
    {
        get { return _childs; }
        set
        {
            if (_childs != value)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _childs, value, nameof(Childs));
            }
        }
    }

    public HierarchialTestObjectViewModel(HierarchialTestObject obj)
    {
        var childs = obj.Childs.Select(c => new HierarchialTestObjectViewModel(c)).ToList();
        Path = obj.Path ?? new List<string>();
        Childs = new ObservableCollection<HierarchialTestObjectViewModel>(childs);
        Item = obj.Item;
        Name = obj.Name;
    }

    public void ExpandRecursively()
    {
        IsExpanded = true;
        Childs?.ToList().ForEach(c => c.ExpandRecursively());
    }

    public void CollapseRecursively()
    {
        IsExpanded = false;
        Childs?.ToList().ForEach(c => c.CollapseRecursively());
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What is a `DataContext` for the `TreeView`? How do you initialize a `HierarchialTestObjects` property?

Comment: Consider to post [**M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you never set the `ItemContainerStyle` of the root items. Only for the child items. Therefore the `IsExpanded` and `IsSelected` properties of the root data models are not connected to their `TreeViewItem` data container.

Just set the `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle` to solve the issue:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
  </Style>  
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

**Remarks**

`TreeViewItem.IsSelected` is configured with `BindingMode.TwoWay` by default.
`TreeViewItem.IsSelected` and `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` have their `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` set to `UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` by default, which is the default for *all*  `Dependency
Property` except they are explicitly set to a different trigger, which is the case for only a few properties (e.g. `TextBox.Text` is set to `UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus` by default).
This way you can reduce code and improve readability.